# Erorr after truffle compile in Erc721 openzeppelin contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin, nft

im doing step by step of this [article](https://medium.com/pinata/how-to-build-erc-721-nfts-with-ipfs-e76a21d8f914) and i had a problem on `truffle compile` part.
I've got this error in cmd:

```
Error parsing @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol: ParsedContract.sol:51:72: ParserError: Expected '{' but got reserved keyword 'override'
function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC165, IERC165) returns (bool) {
                                                                   ^------^
```

my contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract Uniken is ERC721{

using Counters for Counters.Counter;
Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
mapping(string => uint8) hashes;


  constructor() public ERC721("Uniken", "Ukn") {
   }
  
  function awardItem(address recipient, string memory hash, string memory metadata)
  public
  returns (uint256)

  {  
      require(hashes[hash] != 1);
        hashes[hash] = 1;  
        _tokenIds.increment(); 
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current(); 
        _mint(recipient, newItemId); 
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, metadata);  
        return newItemId;
  }

}
```

I'd be thankfull if anyone tell me whatis the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it isn't seeing the ERC165 contract that ERC721 extends from. That function that it is getting stuck on should be overriding a function of the same name in ERC165, but the truffle compiler doesn't see a function named supportsInterface() in a class that ERC721 inherits from. So I would check to make sure everything imported in the ERC721 smart contract is in the right place in your folder structures, and that ERC721 is correctly inheriting ERC165.

Answer (score 0):

After  made some research , I was in truffle version 5.0 and update to the latest version of truffle -> v5.4.6, I am now able to compile